# Does it make sense to send whole Object to frontend (incl. password)?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following database table:

```
User 
----------
userId (int)
name (varchar)
email (varchar)
password (varchar) //is hashed
creditCard (varchar)
```

During login I'm validating email and password on the database, returning name and userId.

```
@NamedQuery(name = User.LOGIN, query = "SELECT u.userId, u.name FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email AND u.password = :password")
```

which returns me an ArrayList which I'm not able to cast into a User Object.

```
0 =
  > 0 = 1
  > 1 = "Bob"
```

So I'm creating always a new Object, setting the values and returning this Object to the UI.

```
User newUser = new User;
newUser.setUserId(userObject[0]);
newUser.setName(userObject[1]);
```

I could also `select u from User u`, cast the result to the User Object and send to Frontend, but I fear that it's unsafe to send the password, creditcard details,... to the frontend.

Now my question, should I simply return the whole User Object and send it to the frontend or would there be a third solution to not always have to create new Object?

Comment: It's unsafe to have stored the password to start with, unless it's salted and hashed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe of course it's hashed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that it makes no sense to send the original user object to the front end because:

- What you don't send to the frontend cannot be stolen or otherwise retrieved by e.g. malicious scripts running on the client side (no matter if hashed or not)
- You usually don't want to send unnecessary data, which might matter when your users are on a slow mobile connection with poor signal strength and your future user object also includes a 4 MB profile picture
- You might want to decouple front end and back end by adding an additional transport layer so that changes in the back end do not automatically lead to changes in the front end or you might want to combine multiple calls to the back end into one big single transport object, both requiring the creation of a new object anyway

On a side note: Similar to the password you should probably also not store credit card numbers in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

While sending password between frontend and backend might be tolerable provided, the connection between them is secure, storing the password as plain text in database is not. For a couple of reasons:

1. Developers can have access to the passwords of users.
2. If data is stolen, passwords can be easily read.

The passwords should be hashed before storing and hashes should be compared. There should be no possibility to recover it from the hash.

Comment: I'm of course hasing the passwords and comparing the hashed password with the hashed one on the database. But I'm not sure if to send the hole User object back and forward, including hashed password and other things like maybe creditcard numer or social securitynumber,...